# Given two active Network adapters for Wi-Fi and Ethernet, which one is set as the default on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

**Specs**

Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
Version 10.0.22631 Build 22631

**Problem**

Two connections, one Computer.

[image: net]

Recently playing games and surfing the web was very glitchy and slow. Somehow, the Wi-Fi was the active connection instead of the more reliable ethernet.

**Question**

Is there a way on Windows 11 to specify the order of connections so that the ethernet takes precedence?

To show *Connected* interfaces, I've run this PowerShell Command:

`Get-NetIPInterface | Where-Object { $_.ConnectionState -eq 'Connected' }`

The output lists the `InterfaceMetric`

```
ifIndex InterfaceAlias                  AddressFamily NlMtu(Bytes) InterfaceMetric Dhcp     ConnectionState PolicyStore
------- --------------                  ------------- ------------ --------------- ----     --------------- -----------
6       VMware Network Adapter VMnet8   IPv6                 65536              35 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
20      VMware Network Adapter VMnet1   IPv6                  1500              35 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
25      Ethernet 2                      IPv6                  1500              35 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
13      Wi-Fi                           IPv6                  1500              35 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv6            4294967295              75 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
6       VMware Network Adapter VMnet8   IPv4                 65536              35 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
20      VMware Network Adapter VMnet1   IPv4                  1500              35 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
25      Ethernet 2                      IPv4                  1500              35 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
13      Wi-Fi                           IPv4                  1500              35 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv4            4294967295              75 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
```

Notice the Wi-Fi and Ethernet both have the same metric 35?

**Update**

Based upon the answer, I've changed the metric for Ethernet to 1 and Wi-Fi to 2, then **REBOOTED**. The metrics have now changed to 1 and 2. :)

```
ifIndex InterfaceAlias                  AddressFamily NlMtu(Bytes) InterfaceMetric Dhcp     ConnectionState PolicyStore
------- --------------                  ------------- ------------ --------------- ----     --------------- -----------
6       VMware Network Adapter VMnet8   IPv6                 65536              35 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
20      VMware Network Adapter VMnet1   IPv6                  1500              35 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
25      Ethernet 2                      IPv6                  1500              35 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
13      Wi-Fi                           IPv6                  1500              45 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv6            4294967295              75 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
6       VMware Network Adapter VMnet8   IPv4                 65536              35 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
20      VMware Network Adapter VMnet1   IPv4                  1500              35 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
25      Ethernet 2                      IPv4                  1500               1 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
13      Wi-Fi                           IPv4                  1500               2 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv4            4294967295              75 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally wired Ethernet has a lower metric than Wireless, so if both are active, Ethernet takes preference.  Most users are happy with this.

If you have both connected, and wish Wireless to have preference by going to Advanced Network Settings and setting Wireless to a lower metric than Wired.

Set Ethernet (Wired) to be lower if you wish Ethernet to take preference.

Do not set both to the same. Use one or the other.

I can and have changed the active outside wireless to be higher than Ethernet, and when I plug in the Ethernet cable. it takes over. I do this for a faster LAN connection occasionally and it works fine.

Here is a screen shot to assist you.

[image: Wireless / Wired Metric settings]

Answer (score 2):

Windows, by [default](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/change-wi-fi-network-connection-priority-order-in-windows-11.13552/), prefers network connectivity in the following order, and *should* prefer the Ethernet access over Wi-Fi.

1. Ethernet
2. Wi-Fi
3. Mobile broadband modem

However, if Wi-Fi is given preference, you can try changing it to a metered connection:

- Open *Network & Internet Settings*
- Select the current Wi-Fi and click on *Properties*.
- Set *Metered connection* to *On*.
- Optionally, set a data limit.

[image: Set Wi-Fi Metered]

Comment: In my case, both Wi-Fi and Ethernet had a default metric of 35. It seems odd that Windows would use extra internal settings such as a `Metered Connection` when deciding which connection to prioritize. As for my setup, Ethernet should ALWAYS have precedence over Wi-Fi, so I've set them to 1 and 2 respectively.